# How to Build | Code an Indeed Bot to Automate Applying to Applications?

Tags: python, automation, project, build-automation

I’m interested in and researching how to build an indeed bot that applies to applications for me as well as all the other application job sites. so I can work a lot smarter and have more leads and clients coming in.

I want to automate this process as it takes personal time to apply to each application. and I want to create a bot that goes to all the job sites for me and apply for me.
such as:

Indeed
Glassdoor
Monster
Linkedin
etc…

I see there is a lot of great web developers and coders in this forum. and I know you guys have the skills and knowledge to give amazing information on this subject!

How should I go about doing this?

How do I get started on this project?

What are the steps I need to make to make this happen?

Comment: This post is open ended and could lead to subjective or opinion based answers.  Can you re-frame the post with specific questions?

Comment: Ok I did. Would love  your feedback! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The only other recommendation I can make would be to pick a tool set (e.g., a programming language, database, operating system) and ask specific questions about those around a bit more detail about how you would do things.  Otherwise, good work.